# How to selectively print only WARNING and/or ERROR in a Jupyter Notebook (as well as CoLab Notebook) cell?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Users can get frustrated with a lot of text output after executing a Jupyter Notebook cell. They can suppress the **entire** output by using magic command `%%capture`. However, sometime they are interested in ERROR/WARNING messages (**if any**), and disregard the rest.

Is it possible to selectively display **ERROR/WARNING messages** only? The trick should also work with Google CoLab's Notebook.

[image]